# Import error "No module named cx_Oracle" by Jupyter but Anaconda can see this package on Win10

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, jupyter, cx-oracle

We successfully installed cx_Oracle 8.3.0 for Python 3.8 in Anaconda on Win10 with administrator rights via "python -m pip install C:/...whl --no-deps" because we have no direct access to pypi due to the security reasons, but Jupyter couldn't see this very library even after restarting Jupyter and PC and after reinstallation of the Anaconda together with Jupyter also.

- There are no other Python installations on the PC.
- Command "conda list" shows that the library is in the directory from which Jupyter is importing libraries.
- Command "python -m pip list" can't find this library in the same directory.
- Directory with libraries can be edited only with administrator rights. We performed the same set of actions on the PCs without rights restrictions and had no problem, but in this case we can't change security settings.
- Instantclient path for Oracle is in the PATH variable. Instantcleint is working fine for the base Oracle connection.
- We have tried to use different variants of names for the import of library, but it didn't help.
- We can't switch to OracleDB package due to the older version of Python on our production server, which isn't compatible with this library

What can be the cause of such a different behaviour by Anaconda and Jupyter and what can be done to fix it?

Update: Eventually, reinstallation of the Anaconda and library at question did help, but it required one more restart of the PC.